# BlazeDS - Object that deserialize to actionscript object can't be cast to his subclass (parent)

Tags: java, actionscript-3, blazeds

I am building flex application and using blazeDS to pass objects between java and actionscript.
I have the following java classes (Property that extends BaseProperty) and their actionscript representation.

When I pass the java Property object to the actionscript using blazeDS and trying to cast it as action scipt BaseProperty object I get null.

Why??

It's important to mention that if I cast it as Property everything is fine.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you haven't provided any code you're forcing us to perform psychic debugging - however my guess would be that you haven't registered the base class using:

```
registerClassAlias("BaseProperty", BaseProperty);
```

Comment: LOL, Actually I just found this solution and came here to write the exact thing :) I didn't paste any code because I thought it's a known issue with casting to baseclass. Anyway, thank you very much.

Comment: I have a follow up question: I used registerClassAlias("BaseProperty", BaseProperty);
but couldn't send the server BaseProperty object using blazeDS because blazeDS tried to look for BaseProperty class and not the full name: server.package.BaseProperty. Only after I changed it to registerClassAlias("server.package.BaseProperty", BaseProperty); I managed to send the server a BaseProperty object. So my question is, should I still use registerClassAllias or should I have used a temp variable: var tempBaseProperty:BasePropery = new BasePropery(); ?